# Error: Connection refused issue when trying to connect to a mqtt enabled node server hosted on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, mqtt

So I basically wanted to host a mqtt pub/sub-enabled node server on Heroku. These are 2 guides I refer to:
https://github.com/adamvr/MQTT.js and https://gist.github.com/1826931

The mqtt pub/sub worked well when tested on localhost, deployment on heroku was fine, but when I tried testing on Heroku it didn't work

I tried 2 commands to subscribe, both showed the same errors.

Command 1:

```
mosquitto_sub -p <port> -h <host> -t <topic>
```

Error 1:

```
Error: Connection refused
Unable to connect (13).
```

Command 2:

```
mqtt_sub <port> <host> <topic>
```

Error 2:

```
node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:670:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:661:19)
```

My main.js (server) code is similar to this one - https://gist.github.com/1826931. The error seems more like a node problem than a mqtt pub/sub problem, and I am new to node, so not quite sure how to debug it. I put in some console.log lines but as expected it didn't print since it's not connected. There is a dyno running `node main.js` on Heroku fine.

```
Process  State       Command       
-------  ----------  ------------  
web.1    up for 35m  node main.js
```

Appreciate any advice on this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly Heroku is and how does it work, but did you make sure that the port you are using is indeed open on the server?